# How to create .docx file as a zip file using C#

Tags: c#, zip, document

I need to unzip some ".docx" files, then access the file "document.xml" and perform some modifications on it, finally to zip again the files to ".docx".
The first and second steps are ok using this code:

```
var newPath = zipPath + ".unzipped";
            using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(newPath))
                {
                    Directory.Delete(newPath, true);
                    archive.ExtractToDirectory(newPath);
                }
            }
```

then

```
string path = Path.Combine(zipPath+ @".unzipped\word\document.xml");
            var content = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8);
```

What is not clear for me is how to zip again the files. I have tried this code

```
 ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourceDirectory, destinationFile);
```

but it does not work. When I try to open the .docx with notepad++ it shows some non-readable encoding.

Comment: "When I try to open the .docx with notepad++ it shows some non-readable encoding." - what does Notepad++ normally show for a docx file? I wouldn't *expect* that to work, given that you're opening a compressed format in a text editor.

Comment: If a .docx file is just a renamed .zip file with some particular files inside, then Notepad++ is just going to try and read the text of the zip file, not try and use any intelligence to extract the contents.

Comment: @gunr2171 no the .docx is not just renamed .zip file. I created a normal .docx file, the I give its path and it works fine (It is considered as a zip package)

Comment: @SAliaMunch https://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Word_Document_(DOCX) "DOCX is written in an XML format, which consists of a ZIP archive file containing XML and binaries. Content can be analysed without modification by unzipping the file (e.g. in WinZIP) and analysing the contents of the archive."

Comment: @– Jon Skeet even when I try to open the .docx generated file it does not show any output

Comment: oh no! so I am trying to do something that shouldnt be done?

Comment: In my opinion, yes.


If you want to edit Word files in a program, you should use a library designed for that, rather than try to hack a **very complex** file format.


Start by looking at [Open XML SDK 2.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk)


And look for libraries built on it that make the task more palatable (I use EPPlus but it is for Excel, not Word, there are certainly some on NuGet).


(Open XML SDK is not dependent on Office Automation, it can be used on a computer without Office, such as a server)